# Does such an algebra morphism $C(S^1)\to C^*\left(\langle a,b \rangle\right)$ exist?

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $C^*(\langle a,b \rangle)$ be the full group $C^*$-algebra of free group on two letters $\langle a, b\rangle$.
Is there an algebra morphism $C(S^1)\to C^*\left(\langle a,b \rangle\right)$ which extends $id_{S^1}\mapsto a$ ?

Note that it is clear what to do on polynomials, namely $f(z)=\sum_k t_kz^k$ is mapped to $\sum_k t_k a^k$.

Comment: Yes. $C(S^1)$ is the universal $C^{\ast}$-algebra generated by a unitary, so given any unital $C^{\ast}$-algebra $A$ and unitary $u\in A$, there is a homomorphism $\rho : C(S^1) \to A$ such that $\rho(z) = a$.

Comment: Is the morphism $\rho$ uniquely determined by $\rho(z)=a$? @PrahladVaidyanathan

Comment: Yes, because $C(S^1)$ is generated by $z$ as a $C^{\ast}$-algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea works in general. In a C$^*$-algebra you have continuous functional calculus on normal operators (and $a$ is a unitary), so you can define $\gamma:C(S^1)\to C^*(\langle a,b\rangle)$ by 
$$
\gamma(f)=f(a). 
$$
This works because, with $a$ a unitary, you have $\sigma(a)\subset S^1$ (it is actually an equality, but we don't need it here).